# Select only one checkbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Yes/No checkbox, in which I want the user to select only one. I have a java script, but it’s not working no errors.

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HaveYouApplied, htmlAttributes: new { id = "chkYes", onchange = "chkBox1", @checked = true, @class = "big-checkbox" })

Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HaveYouApplied, htmlAttributes: new { id = "chkNo", onchange = "chkBox2", @checked = false, @class = "big-checkbox" })

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#chkYes").change(function () {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (ischecked) {
            $("#chkNo").prop("checked");
        }
    });

    $("#chkNo").change(function () {
        var ischecked = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (ischecked) {
            $("#chkYes").prop("checked");
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Why in the world are you doing this? It simply makes no sense. You either have one checkbox, or you have 2 radio buttons with values `true` and `false` that bind to your `HaveYouApplied` property.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery:

Add the class 'chkBx' to each of your check boxes in the group you want to restrict to only one checked.

```
$('.chkBx').change(function () {
        $(".chkBx").not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HaveYouApplied, htmlAttributes: new { id = "chkYes", onchange = "ModifyCheckBoxes('chkYes')", @checked = true, @class = "big-checkbox" })

Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.HaveYouApplied, htmlAttributes: new { id = "chkNo", onchange = "ModifyCheckBoxes('chkNo')", @checked = false, @class = "big-checkbox" })

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ModifyCheckBoxes(Id) {
    if (document.getElementById(Id).checked) {
        if (Id == "chkNo") {
            document.getElementById("chkYes").checked = false;
        } else if (Id == "chkYes") {
            document.getElementById("chkNo").checked = false;
        }
    };
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here should be everything you need to accomplish this in any ASP.Net applicaion, including Core, as that's what I'm using at the moment.
PLEASE NOTE: You will need jQuery for this to work.

Firstly, place your checkboxes in your page. Here I'm binding to a model and the properties are bool, so EditorFor knows it's a bool, so renders it as a checkbox automatically, wihtout you have to specify @Html.CheckboxFor().

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PreferEmail, new { htmlAttributes = new { data_group="PreferredContact", title="I prefer to be contacted by Email", @class = "form-check-input select-one" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PreferPhone, new { htmlAttributes = new { data_group="PreferredContact", title="I prefer to be contacted by Phone", @class = "form-check-input select-one" } })
```

'form-check-input' is just a Bootstrap class in order to style the checkbox.
Tag the checkboxes you want to apply this 'select only one' logic to, with a CSS class name. I've chosen 'select-one'.
Add the attribute 'data-group' and give each checkbox in the 'select only one' family the same data-group name, this is for if you have multiple groups of checkboxes in one page.

```
var checkboxes = {
selectOne: {
    init: function () {
        var self = this;
        $(".select-one").on("change", function () {
            $(`[data-group=${$(this).attr("data-group")}`).not(this).prop("checked", false);
        })
    },
    vallidate: function (grp) {
        var self = this;
        if ($(`[data-group=${grp}]:checked`).length == 0) {
            //validation.addError("At least one option must be selected!");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}};
```

This is the only required jQuery/Javascript. Add it to your HEAD section in the HTML, or somewhere in your page.

Then, on page load, just call like this:-

```
$(document).ready(function () { checkboxes.selectOne.init(); }
```

There is a validation method in there for good measure, so if you have client-side validation, you can call checkboxes.selectOne.validate('your group'), which will return true if at least one item is checked, and false if no items are checked.
Mine feeds in to my main client-side validation library (hence the commented out line) by adding a new Error to display if necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use a radio button which is intended for this exact scope?

Comment: Aesthetics probably ‍♂️